# Write a recursive function to get the factorial of any given number in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, factorial

I am new to Haskell Programming. I tried to write a Haskell function to get the factorial of any given number by recursion. But it gets stack overflow exception.

```
  factor x = x * (factor x-1)
```

Comment: What do you think will happen when you compute `factor 0`, and why?

Comment: All recursive functions require a base case that doesn't require recursion to produce an answer.

Comment: Also note that `factor x-1` means `(factor x)-1` and not `factor (x-1)` -- add parentheses. (And add a base case)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error since your recursion doesn't have a base case. You need a way for the program to stop once a certain condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing the factorial calculation - recursion, product, or folds.

```
factorial n = product [1..n]    -- product algorithm

import Data.List
factorial n = foldl' (*) 1 [1..n]     -- fold algorithm
```

In the case of recursion, we always have two things:

1. The base case
2. How to get from one case to another

Considering some factorials:

```
1! = 1
2! = 2 x 1 = 2 x 1!
3! = 3 x 2 x 1 = 3 x 2!
4! = 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 4 x 3!
```

The base case, the final case, is 1!, or 1. The way of getting from n! to (n-1)! is to multiply n by (n-1)!

When we set out the factorial calculation, we have to do the base case first, otherwise Haskell will pattern match on the general case and never get to the base case. Also, it is a good practice to explicitly specify the types, in this case Integer (arbitrary sized integer) to Integer (arbitrary sized integer).

```
 factor :: Integer -> Integer
 factor 1 = 1
 factor n = n * factor (n-1)
```